# Speed up redering of simple table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am loading content of a server and putting it on a website.

```
$("#mydiv").load ("/content");
```

The content is a very long HTML-table (60k rows with 2 cols, simple strings, no css).
Content-string is ~3.5MB, loading needs 1 second.

But the problem is that it takes ~1 minute for the browser to show it.

Is there any way I can speed the rendering up - without rethinking my presentation (etc. paginated list)?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do anything to make that content render quicker than that... anyway there's the chance that such long time is required because you are performing some javascript over that table? In my experience it would take some seconds (10s maybe) for a range of 30k rows but just because I'm doing heavy computation navigating the dom

Comment: Loading as a single string should be the quickest method, but it's the size that's the issue.  Some things that can help, but are normally used when adding line-by-line:  1) Ensure HTML is well formed (tbody `<tr>` + `</tr>` etc) so that the browser doesn't need to make any implied additions   2) used fixed column widths - using [`<col>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col) can help here or set widths in the thead/th's.  Every time a `tr` or `td` is added, the *entire* `table` has to be recalculated to fit cells to content - fixing the widths stops this.

Comment: You try a `<div>` based layout rather than `<table>`    `<table>`s are notoriously slow to render.

Comment: Are you using datatables.net?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot speed up by receiving all the data at once.

There is a way to get the total number of records and add (`append`) them to the table using `ajax` while looping.

Comment: From the question: *loading needs 1 second*... *the problem is* .. *takes ~1 minute ..to show it* - receiving doesn't appear to be the problem.  Though receiving in batches could help.

Comment: 3.5M data cannot be loaded in 1 second.
First of all, there is a way to display data that can be loaded in 1 second and continue to add it as ajax.

Comment: Why not?  are you on dial-up?  ;)

Comment: I mean rendering, how about to get json array and then loop for appending to table.